# Visual Studio Code Analysis Dispose implementation warnings

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis

I have the following code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Dispose.
/// </summary>
public override sealed void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

/// <summary>
/// Dispose.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="disposing">
/// Disposing parameter.
/// </param>
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
    }
     Clear();
     base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

And have the following warnings:

> Warning   435 CA2215 : Microsoft.Usage : Ensure that method 'DSDump.Dispose()' calls base.'DSDump.Dispose()' in all possible control flow paths.
>   Warning   436 CA1063 : Microsoft.Design : Remove 'DSDump.Dispose()', override Dispose(bool disposing), and put the dispose logic in the code path where 'disposing' is true.

I don't have any ideas why... All looks OK from my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your base class is defined incorrectly.

`public void Dispose()` should not be a virtual method in your base class.  It should handle the GC suppression and call the virtual `protected virtual void Dispose(bool)` method, which is the one you should override.

Comment: +1, Microsoft does have sample code to show what is the recommended, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx

Comment: @LexLi Note that the MS guidelines and sample code only shows how to implement the base class, but not a derived class.  For that, see: http://reedcopsey.com/2009/03/30/idisposable-part-2-subclass-from-an-idisposable-class/